# Confused about linux terminal command switches, "-[switch] vs -[switch]-"?

Tags: linux, terminal, command-line-arguments

Most command switches are entered with a single dash like "-p", but others can also be used with a another dash attached to the end of the switch to change it's functionality, like this "-p-".

I use "-p" only as a generic example.

I would really appreciate if someone could explain how adding an additional dash at the end of a command switch changes the functionality of the switch in a general sense.

Thank you in advance for the help.

An example:

nmap –sT -p- -Pn 192.168.18.132

So how is the -p- switch different from the -p?

Like is there any convention as to how an additional dash modifies the behavior of a switch?

Comment: Can you give an example of a command where the option can be terminated with a dash?

Comment: I edited the original post, sorry for not being clear

Comment: I don't think you'll have an answer that covers many programs. In this case, -p awaits a port range afterwards. The port range is in the form {start}-{end} where start and end can both be omitted and default to 1 and 65535.

Comment: For many commands which expect a file after an option, a dash means stdout.

Comment: @user2313067 he asked what `-p-` meant with `nmap –sT -p- -Pn 192.168.18.132”` with no number after it and you didn't address that

Comment: @Patrick where did you get that nmap line with `-p-`?

Comment: @barlop I did say both could be omitted and default to 1 and 65535, so -p- is equivalent to -p1-65535 and scans all ports.

Comment: @user2313067 fair enough. BTW, when `-` means stdout, does there have to be a space between the switch and the dash, or is the space optional?

Comment: @barlop as far as I know, it usually doesn't have to. `wget` for example has the `-O` option to select the output file. `-O-` prints the downloaded file on stdout.

Comment: @barlop from a book I'm reading, "The Basics of Hacking and Penetration Testing" by Patrick Engebretson

Comment: So is it safe to say then that for many commands, "-" at then end of a switch mean "stdout", but for some command it's instead treated as a sort of "different special value"? Like in the example I gave, it appears as though the dash is being treated as "1-65535" like @barlop pointed out

Comment: @Patrick even in the nmap case it's not that the dash is a special value or that it represents a special value.   There are two cases, one is where a switch takes a file(e.g. user231's wget example - i've seen that with other commands too), the other case is a switch that takes or can take a range of numbers.  A switch taking a range of numbers isn't that common.  And there's no point saying `-p-`  because if you don't specify `-p` at all then it will do `-p1-65535`

Comment: ahh ok I understand now thanks for the help! Really appreciate it!